# Cannot see Azure Function name when creating Azure Event Grid Subscription

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid, azure-blob-trigger

So using VS 2019, I created a Blob Trigger function (v2) and deployed it to Azure, against a blob storage (v2). If I upload a file the function is executed and the file in the blob storage gets processed successfully. So all good here.

I am now looking to create an Azure Event Grid subscription (via the Azure portal) to attach to the trigger and the storage, however, I cannot see the function name.

[image]

After selecting the Subscription, Resource Group & Function App in the right-side blade, the Slot dropdown only has one value i.e. 'Production'. Upon selecting 'Production', the Function dropdown is empty and neither does it allow me to type in a function name.

Has anyone faced this before? I would appreciate any insights in this matter.

Thanks & Regards,
Noel

Comment: The event handler resource must be the EventGridTrigger function, not the BlobTrigger. So, create the empty EventGridTrigger in the portal and you should see in the combobox this function.

Comment: Roman & @huryshen, Thank you for your responses. That worked pretty well. I would like to mark Roman's response as the answer since it was the first response but I cannot do that as it is a comment. 

Roman, would you like to post your response as an answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: That's fine, I have no problem when you will mark the answer from @huryshen and my comment too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roman said in comment, you just need to create a EventGridTrigger function in your function app. And then we can select it in the Function dropdown.
[image]

Comment: @Roman & HuryShen.....Once again Thank you very much for your responses. Just wanted to leave a note here.....I could not create the EventGridTrigger from the portal as I had created the BlobTrigger function through VS2019. I had to go back to VS2019, create the EventGridTrigger there and publish it. I read somewhere that you can use either the one of the 2 i.e. Azure Portal or VS2019. Thanks.